# Excel search for cell references in formulas

Tags: excel, search, excel-2003, worksheet-function

I inherited a big model and have been trying to reverse engineer some of the formulas. There are a lot of fields. I am not sure if everyone of them is necessary.

Is it possible to search an Excel document (with 5 worksheets) to find if say, AZ12 is used in any formula? Or $AZ12 or $AZ$12?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Tools > Formula Auditing > Trace Precedents or Trace Dependents (Excel 2003)

Formulas > Trace Precedents or Trace Dependent (Excel 2010)

Comment: Yep, that's one way to do it on a per cell basis.

Comment: Excel 2010: Formulas > Trace Precedents or Trace Dependents

Answer (score 1):

I bought the add-in [Formula Manager](http://www.ozgrid.com/Services/Excel_Formula_Add-in.htm) to do this.
If you want to do it yourself, you'll have to implement it in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Search > Options > Within: Workbook > Look in: Formulas

The upside is that you can broaden the search for example by omitting the row number, or narrow it by including pieces of a formula you want to find.  For an inherited file I would Find All '='.

The downside is you have to check with and without dollar signs, a total of four searches for the original example.