# Excel - Find out the cell reference to particular value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one value in say 'Sheet2'. I have to find out the cell reference from all the values in say 'Sheet1'. Please answer quick, it may be easy but I need quick help on this.

Comment: What exactly you want? Explain with example.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152934/excel-search-for-cell-references-in-formulas and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787486/excel-formula-to-find-reference-used-by-other-cell and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248820/find-all-references-to-a-cell. BTW, search before ask & ask in detail in future to get prompt and good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use menu `Formulas / Trace Dependents`. Then follow the blue arrows to find the referenced cells.

P.S. "Please answer quick, it may be easy but I need quick help on this." is not encouraging. Welcome to StackOverflow.